# Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.1): Extracting archive not run

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-10

Friends.
i have this problem When i want to create a project or i want to update other dependencies with `composer update` command. the whole process is left in `Extracting file`

I already cleared cache, I already proved that I have internet. and I also cancel the operation with ctrl-c or ctrl-x.

What could be happening?

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app-2
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./example-app-2"
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.1)
  - Downloading laravel/laravel (v10.2.1)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.1): Extracting archive
```

Now, show this error

```
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./example-app-2" 
Info from repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine 
Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.1) 
- Downloading laravel/laravel (v10.2.1) 
- Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.1): Extracting archive 
Install of laravel/laravel failed The following exception is caused by a process timeout Check getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#process-timeout for details In Process.php line 1204: 
The process "rm -rf '/home/ubuntu/vendor/composer/925d6817'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section